# Mutating Error on a trigger to calculate average cost

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables, PRODUCTS, and STATE_PRICE.  The prices for each product vary by state.  The PRODUCTS table tracks the average cost of each product across all states.  I am trying to write a trigger that will update the average price of the item in the PRODUCTS table when the a price is inserted, updated, or deleted in the STATE_PRICE table.  I have written the following trigger, which compiles, but when I test it out, I get a mutating error message.  I understand the concept of the mutating error, that I am trying to update a table that a trigger is being performed on, but my I am actually trying to update the PRODUCTS table while the trigger is being performed on the STATE_PRICE table.

```
create or replace trigger trg_avg_cost
after insert or update or delete on state_price
for each row

declare
w_price state_price.list_price%type;
w_product state_price.productid%type;

begin
w_price := :new.list_price;
w_product := :new.productid;

update products
set avg_cost_per_unit = (select avg(w_price) from state_price
where productid = w_product);

end;
/
```

The specific error message I get says:

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table STATE_PRICE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TRG_AVG_COST", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRG_AVG_COST'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Comment: I think you've to use Pragma Autonomous_transaction in declare and check again

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a refrential integrity constraint ( on productid), which can also raise the same error. If thats the case the below link can help you to avoid the error.

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936

Comment: ORA-04091 will only be thrown from within a row trigger if an SQL statement within the trigger attempts to access the table on which the trigger exists.  Foreign key violation result in different errors (ORA-02291, ORA-02292, or ORA-02298 depending on circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

Within a row trigger no SQL statement can access the table on which the trigger exists.  Your `SELECT AVG(W_PRICE) FROM STATE_PRICE WHERE PRODUCTID = W_PRODUCT` is what's causing the error.  The classic way to get around this limitation is to use a compound trigger - documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005).  Also see my answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184631/creating-a-trigger-that-deletes-a-row-when-an-attribute-becomes-negative-oracle/10195691#10195691) for an example of implementing a compound trigger.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It looks like a compound trigger is just the thing I need!